# Adversarial/Naive Pairing with TDD: How effective is it?

Tags: tdd, pair-programming

A friend of mine was explaining how they do ping-pong pairing with TDD at his workplace and he said that they take an "adversarial" approach. That is, when the test writing person hands the keyboard over to the implementer, the implementer tries to do the bare simplest (and sometimes wrong thing) to make the test pass.

For example, if they're testing a GetName() method and the test checks for "Sally", the implementation of the GetName method would simply be:

```
public string GetName(){
    return "Sally";
}
```

Which would, of course, pass the test (naively).

He explains that this helps eliminate naive tests that check for specific canned values rather than testing the actual behavior or expected state of components. It also helps drive the creation of more tests and ultimately better design and fewer bugs.

It sounded good, but in a short session with him, it seemed like it took a lot longer to get through a single round of tests than otherwise and I didn't feel that a lot of extra value was gained.

Do you use this approach, and if so, have you seen it pay off?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is based on the team's personality.  Every team has a personality that is the sum of its members.  You have to be careful not to practice passive-aggressive implementations done with an air of superiority. Some developers are frustrated by implementations like

> `return "Sally";`

This frustration will lead to an unsuccessful team.  I was among the frustrated and did not see it pay off.  I think a better approach is more oral communication making suggestions about how a test might be better implemented.

Comment: I can see people getting angry at this, but at least on this guy's team, they were friends and they realized that they weren't being smart-asses, just trying to flesh out the best possible tests they could, so it worked out well for them

Answer (score 2):

It can be very effective.

It forces you to think more about what test you have to write to get the other programmer to write the correct functionality you require.

You build up the code piece by piece passing the keyboard frequently

It can be quite tiring and time consuming but I have found that its rare I have had to come back and fix a bug in any code that has been written like this

Comment: + 1 I have found this as well. There was a lot less of the 'happy-path analysis' that can be easy to fall into when programming alone.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this approach.  It doesn't work with all pairs; some people are just naturally resistant and won't give it an honest chance.  However, it helps you do TDD and XP properly.  You want to try and add features to your codebase slowly.  You don't want to write a huge monolithic test that will take lots of code to satisfy.  You want a bunch of simple tests.  You also want to make sure you're passing the keyboard back and forth between your pairs regularly so that both pairs are engaged.  With adversarial pairing, you're doing both.  Simple tests lead to simple implementations, the code is built slowly, and both people are involved throughout the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I like it some of the time - but don't use that style the entire time. Acts as a nice change of pace at times. I don't think I'd like to use the style all of the time.

I've found it a useful tool with beginners to introduce how the tests can drive the implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

(First, off, Adversarial TDD should be fun. It should be an opportunity for teaching. It shouldn't be an opportunity for human dominance rituals. If there isn't the space for a bit of humor then leave the team. Sorry. Life is to short to waste in a negative environment.)

The problem here is badly named tests. If the test looked like this:

```
foo = new Thing("Sally")
assertEquals("Sally", foo.getName())
```

Then I bet it was named "`testGetNameReturnsNameField`". This is a bad name, but not immediately obviously so. The proper name for this test is "`testGetNameReturnsSally`". That is what it does. Any other name is lulling you into a false sense of security. So the test is badly named. The problem is not the code. The problem is not even the test. The problem is the name of the test.

If, instead, the tester had named the test "`testGetNameReturnsSally`", then it would have been immediately obvious that this is probably not testing what we want.

It is therefore the duty of the implementor to demonstrate the poor choice of the tester. It is also the duty of the implementor to write only what the tests demand of them.

So many bugs in production occur not because the code did less than expected, but because it did more. Yes, there were unit tests for all the expected cases, but there were not tests for all the special edge cases that the code did because the programmer thought "I better just do this too, we'll probably need that" and then forgot about it. That is why TDD works better than test-after. That is why we throw code away after a spike. The code might do all the things you want, but it probably does somethings you thought you needed, and then forgot about.

Force the test writer to test what they really want. Only write code to make tests pass and no more.

RandomStringUtils is your friend.